# Meu aplicativo Android não atualiza no teste no dispositivo

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Quando testo o app no emulador, ele exibe normalmente, do jeito que programei. Mas quando passo para o celular, ele exibe um layout que já mudei totalmente, ou seja, ele fica defesado e parece que não atualizou. Alguma ideia ?

Comment: Verifique se .apk que é gerado está sendo atualizado. Sugiro que você renomeie o .apk que está salvo na sua máquina e, posteriormente, faça o processo de criação novamente.

Comment: Então: Meu app tem um Main e 5 fragmentos. Sendo que ao iniciar, no emulador ele vai direto pro fragmento 1. Já no celular, isso não acontecia. Sabe algo sobre isso ?

Comment: Não entendi. Sua pergunta + seu comentário não deixaram claros qual é o problema. [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/54659/edit) sua pergunta e tente deixa-lá mais clara. Talvez, adicionando algum código relevante, fique mais claro.

Comment: Tenta deletar do seu celular e rodar novamente, se não funcionar fecha o Eclipse e tenta rodar de novo, isso já aconteceu comigo.

Comment: Pra resumir, no emulador fica totalmente diferente do dispositivo. No emulador ele executa de uma forma e no dispositivo, de outra. É algum problema ou é normal ?

Comment: Já tentou navegar até a pasta onde se encontra seu APK e instala-lo manualmente tanto no emulador quanto no seu device?